# NetworkX MultiDiGraph doesn't get printed

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, nonetype

I am trying to print an instance of [NetworkX MultiDiGraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html#networkx.MultiDiGraph) as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_node(0)
print(G)
```

My understanding is that since `G` is an instance of a class, it should print something to the string even if `__str__` is not implemented. However, this only prints a blank line. I also tested whether this is a `NoneType` object:

```
isinstance(G, nx.MultiDiGraph)
```

This returns `True`. How is this possible? If it is relevant, I am passing this graph to some other package which is returning an error related to `NoneType` input. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you tell us why you expect it to print something?  I'm not familiar with that.  Secondly, and probably more importantly - what is your goal in asking it to print?

Comment: @Joel: Because it's a class instance and when you print an object, it is always printed in python as far as I know. Even `x=None`, followed by `print(x)` prints `None` to the screen. I want to print it because passing that graph to another package is throwing an error related to `NoneType`.

Comment: @Joel: I looked at the implementation of the class and there is no `__str__` implemented. I then expect it to use `__repr_` automatically when I print an instance and print the object representation to the screen. When I manually implemented `__str__`  inside this class, then it printed a custom message!

Comment: Can you give us the command you're using and the full error message you're getting from the other package?  I'd be a little surprised if the error you're describing results from this.

Comment: @Joel: Okay I reported this to the author of the package and it was actually a bug. TBH, the other package is not supposed to take in multigraphs but I passed it without realizing it. On the bright side, the author said that the multigraph to simple graph conversion will be implemented in future. Still, I am not sure why shouldn't the `__repr__` be called by `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networkx allows you to name a graph, which is what you get when you print the graph.  So for example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiDiGraph(name = 'myG')
G.add_node(0)
print(G)
> myG
```

The name defaults to an empty string.  So that is what is being printed.  I think it's not obvious from the code, but at [this link](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/classes/graph.html#Graph), the definition of the `Graph` class is given.  In it, `__str__` is defined to return the graph name.  The graph name is defined as

```
@property
    def name(self):
        """String identifier of the graph.

        This graph attribute appears in the attribute dict G.graph
        keyed by the string `"name"`. as well as an attribute (technically
        a property) `G.name`. This is entirely user controlled.
        """
        return self.graph.get("name", "")
```

So the default name is an empty string.  Now you've used a `MultiDiGraph`, so this is hidden away - a `MultiDiGraph` is built on a `DiGraph`, which is built on a `Graph`, so hidden in all of that, if the `MultiDiGraph` isn't given a name, it defaults to an empty string.